# scenario generating programming language

Tags: scenarios

I am trying to remember the name of a programming language I stumbled upon maybe a month ago. I totally forget the name, that's why I'm asking you. It had something to do with generating stories/scenarios. Example: you'd set a variable "events" and type it something like this:

```
events {
 eat
 drink
 swim
 walk
}
```

And then you'd write the scenario like this:

```
output: "I like to" {events}
```

The syntax is probably all wrong, but I hope you get the idea. It's so you can easily generate stories/scenarios. Please tell me any name of a programming language you know that's like this. Thanks

Comment: are you talking about "R"?

Comment: No. It was much longer.